# Why does defining CodingKeys for SOME properties require an initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Compiles fine with no problems:

```
class User: Codable {
    let name: String
    let email: String
}
```

However, if we have a property not represented by a CodingKey, it demands an initializer:

```
class User: Codable { // Class 'User' has no initializers
    let name: String
    let email: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "username"
    }
}
```

Why does it decide that a lack of synthesized initializers are the problem, instead of having a warning or error requiring a CodingKey? Why does this break conformance to Decodable?

Edit: Since some people seem to be confused, I'm not asking how to resolve the error. That is obvious. I'm asking what is happening in the Codable protocol when you don't specify a CodingKey for a required property.

Comment: You could simply assign a default value to email so a coding key to the email property would not be required.

Comment: You know what the problem is, even if the error message isn’t very good.

Answer (score 4):

A class with at least one property that doesn't have a default value needs an initializer in order to initialize that property.

```swift
class User {
    let name: String
    let email: String
}
```

> Class 'User' has no initializers

When you conform to `Codable`, or more specifically `Decodable` as you well noted, the class gets a synthesized initializer, namely `User.init(from: Decoder)`, which fixes above issue. This synthesized initializer will use coding keys named after the properties.

```swift
class User: Decodable { ... }
```

As soon as you define an enum within `User` called `CodingKeys` (the exact name is important), the synthesis of the `Decodable` conformance will require that there is a key **for each property**. In other words, as soon as one key deviates from the property name, you have to define a coding key for each property.

The following does that and compiles:

```swift
class User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let email: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "username"
        case email
    }
}
```

If not specifying the `email` key, the compiler will not know how to set that property, only the developer would know how. Hence, the compiler will not synthesize it for you and you have to.

There might be a natural default as shown here:

```swift
class User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let email: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "username"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)

        // Default email:
        email = "\(name)@example.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is throwing the first in a line of errors caused by the second example.  If you added an initializer it would next probably tell you about something related to your lack of codingkey for the name property.  However, when you don't define CodingKeys, it does is able to create CodingKeys as well as the default initializer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're not going to need a CodingKey for `email`, you still have to declare its case, without any value as in:

```
   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case name = "username"
     case email
   }
```